# How do I investigate the cause of a JVM crash?

Tags: java, crash, jvm, jvm-crash

One day ago, after a few months of normal working, our java app starts to crash occasionally with the following error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (safepoint.cpp:247), pid=2075, tid=140042095163136
#  guarantee(PageArmed == 0) failed: invariant
#
# JRE version: 6.0_23-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (19.0-b09 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /var/chat/jSocketer/build/hs_err_pid2075.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

I looked in hs_err_pid2075.log and saw that there was an active thread, that processed a network communication. However there wasn't any application or environment changes done in the last few months. Also there wasn't any load growth.
What can I do to understand, what is the reason of crash? Are there any common steps to investigate a jvm crash?

UPD
http://www.wuala.com/ubear/public

Comment: JVM crashes are very rare in my experience.  They point to bugs in the JVM and can't easily be worked around.  I'd consider upgrading your JRE if you can.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_6_updates

Comment: Please post the contents of hs_err_pid2075.log

Comment: http://www.wuala.com/ubear/public/hs_err_pid2075.log

Comment: It says your old gen is 98% full, does it happen on every crash?

Comment: No,in other times it uses from 5 to 13 percents.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The crash is in the JVM, not in external native code. However, the operation it crashed on has been initiated by and external DLL.

This line in the hs_err_pid file explains the operation that crashed:

```
VM_Operation (0x00007f5e16e35450): GetAllStackTraces, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x0000000040796000
```

Now, thread 0x0000000040796000 is

```
0x0000000040796000 JavaThread "YJPAgent-Telemetry" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2115, stack(0x00007f5e16d36000,0x00007f5e16e37000)]
```

which is a thread created by Yourkit. "GetAllStackTraces" is something that a profiler needs to call in order to do sampling. If you remove the profiler, the crash will not happen.

With this information It's not possible to say what causes the crash, but you can try the following: Remove all -XX VM parameters, -verbose:gc and the debugging VM parameters. They might interfere with the profiling interface of the JVM.

**Update**

Code that calls `java.lang.Thread#getAllStackTraces()` or `java.lang.Thread#getStackTrace()` may trigger the same crash

Comment: Really, it is cool. But other instance of server crashes without using yjp. Thank you, I'll check for requested safepoint in other crash dumps.

Comment: Requesting threads from other crashes: YJPAgent-Telemetry
SocketAcceptorIoProcessor-0.0, AnonymousIoService-6, AnonymousIoService-14, AnonymousIoService-4, AnonymousIoService-7

Comment: @ubear see my edit. It would be interesting to see a crash log from a run without the yourkit profiler

Comment: You can see it at http://www.wuala.com/ubear/public . In the other crashes RevokeBias was called.

Comment: @ubear Interesting, that is a common crash. Again, I would try without -XX VM parameterss, -verbose:gc and the debugging VM parameters.

Comment: For now it works fine, after server rebooting. The server had a big uptime. The most strange thing, is that there  wasn't this bug before, and yesterday it happens.

Answer (score 5):

The two times I've witnessed recurring JVM crashes were both due to hardware failure, namely RAM. Running a [memtest utility](http://www.memtest.org/) is the first thing I'd try.

Answer (score 2):

I can see from the error report that you have the [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/overview/index.jsp) agent loaded. Its telemetry thread is mentioned as the requester for the operation that appears to fail. Try running the application without the [YJP agent](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/75/help/getting_started/running_with_profiler/agent.jsp) to see if you can still reproduce the crash.

Generally, JVM crashes are pretty hard to diagnose. They could happen due to a bug in some JNI code or in the JRE itself. If you suspect the latter, it may be worth submitting a bug report to Oracle.

Either way, I'd recommend to upgrade to the [latest release of Java 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) to make sure it's not a known issue that's already been fixed. At the time of this writing the current release is Java 6 update 29.

Comment: I can't understand why now. I think it hardware issue or anything in user or internal data processing.

Comment: @ubear: Also try running without the YourKit agent. See the updated answer.

Comment: Other instance of server crashes without using yjp.

Comment: @ubear: From these error reports, YJP is clearly not the culprit. I'd urge you to upgrade to the latest JVM to see if the crashes continue to happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not messing with anything that would cause this directly (which basically means using native code or libraries that call native code) then it's almost always down to a bug in the JVM or hardware issue.

If it's been running fine for ages and has now started to crash then it seems to me like the hardware issue is the most likely of the two. Can you run it on another machine to rule out the issue? Of course, it definitely wouldn't hurt to upgrade to the latest Java update as well.

Comment: On the other machine it works fine. But I cant recreate same load on it.

Answer (score 1):

Switching to another version of linux-kernel "fixes" the JVM crush problem (http://forum.proxmox.com/threads/6998-Best-strategy-to-handle-strange-JVM-errors-inside-VPS?p=40286#post40286). It helped me with my real server. There was Ubuntu server 10.04 LTS OS on it with kernel 2.6.32-33 version. So kernel update resolved this issue. JVM has no crash anymore.

Comment: We run our app on the real hardware not VPS, so, this link is hardly relevant. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. As I see we used the older version of the kernel - 2.6.32-5-amd64, when we experienced that crash two years ago. Thank you for your effort.