# JVM Crash, what's wrong?

Tags: java, jvm

I am running into a JVM crash issue and below are dump content. What's RevokeBias? Would somebody help me?

**ERROR**

```
VM_Operation (0x00007f7129fbb450): RevokeBias, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x00007f712452d000
```

Comment: Crash dumps of the JVM usually contain (a lot) more information. Is this everything?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152393/how-do-i-investigate-the-cause-of-a-jvm-crash 
please check out this.

Answer (score 0):

You might be experiencing this bug reported in the Java bug database: [JDK-7116986 : Crash in SafepointSynchronize::begin()](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7116986). Unfortunately there is no solution or workaround yet.